# There are some problems when updating linux mint mate from 18.1 to 18.2

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Всем привет. Я обновил систему к 18.2 "Sonya", но дизайн системиы не поменялся. Может кто знает, как применить новый дизайн?

Comment: А не в темах случайно?

Comment: а как поменять? забиваю themes в пуске - не находит

Comment: @Qwertiy поменял тему, но все равно интерфейс остался прежний.